# Joomla! root directory

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\mywebsites
  \site_1
  \site_2
  \site_n
```

In 'site_2' I have joomla installed, however, I have other folders with resources, php scripts, etc. in one of the 'extra' folders, I have scripts that I'm frequently calling, the trouble comes when I call JURI::base(), it returns the folder in which the script file is, in stead of 'site_2' which I'm expecting.

How can I overcome this simple task?

Comment: I'm looking for a more elegant solution, right now I'm using str_replace to remove extra folders, however, it would be nice if I could get "C:\mywebsites\site_2" by calling one function from a script located in "C:\mywebsites\site_2\a\few\folders\deep\php\script.php"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root directory is defined in `JPATH_BASE`.

It's set in the `index.php` in the Joomla front end and in the /administrator using:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
```

`JURI::base()` returns the base request path.

Answer (score 3):

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(**FILE**));

is return your local drive path.. means c:/site_1/site_2/site_3/

JURI::base()

is return the livefolder path... means http://localhost/site_1/site_2/site_3/

Answer (score 2):

Using **JPATH_ROOT** will give you the path to the joomla installed site.

http://docs.joomla.org/Constants